# C# Getting a column value with lambda and read the value on code behind

Tags: c#, database, lambda

my database table looks like this

[image]

i trying to retrieve the FileURL in the CRUD class file like this :

```
  public IList<string> GetSorted(int listAct)
        {
          IList<Model.story> lstImages = context.stories.ToList();
          return lstImages.Where(c => c.ActivityID == listAct)
                          .Select( a => a.FileURL)
                          .ToList();
        }
```

Am i doing it right? ( new to this )

Then in my aspx , i try to display the value like this ;

```
 protected void btnSort_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dropListActivity.SelectedIndex > 0)// drop down list
        {
                  string imgList = daoStory.GetSorted(Convert.ToInt32(dropListActivity.SelectedItem.Value)).ToString();

            Response.Write(imgList);

        } 
    }
```

Basically the drop down list shows activityID 1 or 2 only , and when i select 1 and click the sort button , it will display the FileURL of '1' and if i select 2 , it will display FileURL of '2' so on from the above database table . However , it now shows *System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]* instead of the FileURL , i want to show the FileURL as stated in the database table , pls help thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, calling `ToList` will cause all the records to be retrieved from the database and processed. That's a pretty big waste of resources when all you need is a single record. I'd Suggest writing your DAO method like this:

```
public string GetFileUrl(int actId)
{
    return context.stories.First(c => c.ActivityID == actId).FileURL;
}
```

And then I think you want to use it like this:

```
protected void btnSort_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dropListActivity.SelectedIndex > 0)// drop down list
    {
        var actId = Convert.ToInt32(dropListActivity.SelectedItem.Value);
        var imageUrl = daoStory.GetFileUrl(actId);

        Response.Write(imageUrl);
    } 
}
```

This method assumes that you'll only have one `FileUrl` for each `ActivityId`. If that's not the case, you can easily modify the DAO code to return a `IEnumerable<string>` and use `Where` instead of `First`, but there's not enough information in the question for me to figure out what the button click handler is supposed to do with the result.

Comment: yes i have one fileurl for each activityid . strangely it doesn't returns the fileurl string instead , its showing 'Model.Story' which is the namespace . actually i am going to display a list of images in grid view form , so the button is to sort the list out based on selection of the drop down list.

Comment: does daoStory.GetFileURL(actID) getting the fileurl column only? i think its retrieving the whole single record

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a list back from the sort method but converting it to a string in the code behind. You have to deal with the list somehow and get the value of whatever element you want.